# What areas of a home are required to be AFCI protected?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, afci

I've got a Crouse Hinds panel with the majority of the breakers being of the ridiculous side connecting type. The panel and breakers are old and beginning to arc due to the lose connection. I've found replacement breakers for the panel but I need to know what areas of the house need to be protected by AFCI type breakers per NEC 2015.

Comment: AFAIK, if you're just replacing breakers, you're grandfathered to the old code and you are not required to install AFCI breakers were there were previously non-AFCI breakers. Even replacing the panel may not change this, though I am less sure.

Comment: Yes, I should have said "I'm working in this panel." The owner (my aunt) just bought the house and the inspector "highly recommended" going AFCIs. I said BS. Then I had to troubleshoot an outlet not working where I found these crazy breakers. She could get away with not doing it but I think she's going for safety. BTW, changing your panel out in CA would indeed require AFCIs. Thanks @DoxyLover.

Comment: **"BTW, changing your panel out in CA would indeed require AFCIs."** ......   @ChiefTwoPencils, do you have written documentation for this? In NY this is NOT required, and I believe most of the rest of the country is the same.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey, I might can find it in writing but my knowledge comes from an inspector. I was considering swapping my 90A 1950's panel and that's what I was told. Given that, perhaps it may be more accurate to say Sacramento specifically. In general, they're pretty on-top of it. Remodeling my kitchen forced me to bring all plumbing fixtures throughout the ENTIRE house up to modern standards; wasn't even doing any work in the bathrooms.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils, well, it's not something I'd doubt considering it's California. That's a pretty totalitarian place. I just wouldn't go simply on an inspector's word. I'd want to see that in writing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to NEC 2014 210.12(A).

> ...kitchens, family rooms, dining rooms, living rooms, parlors, libraries, dens, bedrooms, sunrooms, recreation rooms, closets, hallways, laundry areas, or similar rooms or areas shall be protected...

Comment: Wouldn't it have been easier for them to just say what outlets DON'T require AFCIs?  I think that covers every single room in my house, except the bathroom!

Comment: @Grant Now that dual function circuit interrupters (DFCI) are more common, AFCI protection in bathrooms will probably be in the next code cycle. Pretty much all "*living space*" is covered.

Comment: @Grant, you are right. It has REALLY gotten out of hand.

Comment: @Tester101,  If it needs it  and the OP were to change out the panel, he would also need to bring the grounding of the electrical system up to code also.